# How do I replace a value of a key from a returned JSON object after calling an API using requests.get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Problem Summary:

I am calling an API with requests.get.  The returned JSON object is being saved to a variable as a JSON dictionary:

`data = json.loads(response.text)`

I need to access that dictionary, then replace one of its keys' values, then I need to POST the new dictionary back to the API.  I tried this by creating a function.  The value is originally 'False' and I need to change it to be 'True':

```
def updatedata(data):
    k = 'my_key'
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k == 'my_key':
            data[v] = 'True'

response = requests.get(my_URL, headers=my_headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
updatedata(data)

newlibary = updatedata()
print(newlibrary)
```

The problem that arises is that I can't figure out how to update the JSON library without calling the original JSON library again.  How do I do the usual request.get, then use my function to change the value I need to change, then POST it again to a new API call like requests.post?

Comment: `data[v] = True` instead of `data[v] = 'True'`?

Comment: You need to `return data` in function updatedata.

Comment: What's the "JSON library" and what do you mean by "update the JSON library"?

Comment: @martineau The JSON library is what is returned with "requests.get" API call. I think a more accurate name for it would be json dictionary object.  I need to take a key/value pair from that object and replace it with a new key/value pair.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer please see my responses to the other 2 answers.  Same question applies to you.

Comment: RaptorPete: `json.loads()` returns a Python object according the [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) table in the documentation—which typically aren't "called"—so you would update it like you would the corresponding Python data-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> myDict = {"testing": 1, "testing2": 2, "my_key": 3}
>>>
>>>
>>> def updatedata(data):
...     k = 'my_key'
...     for key, val in data.items():  # use a different variable to reduce confusion
...         if key == 'my_key':
...             data[key] = 'True'  # specify the key, not the value
...     return data  # optional, unless you want to save into a new variable
...
>>>
>>> updatedata(myDict)
>>> myDict
{'testing': 1, 'testing2': 2, 'my_key': 'True'}
>>>
```

Comment: This is not working for me either.  When you ```return data``` at the end there, does that not just call the original requests.get API call? The one that has not yet been updated?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, in that with this function you are modifying the original variable from before the function call. However, any changes you make will persist after the function call. You really don't need the return unless you want to save it into a new variable, which is probably a better practice anyway.

Comment: Another way to be sure of what you're doing is to assign the passed in arg in to a new local variable inside the function and return that instead.

Comment: This works how I need it to, thank you! I do have a question though.  For this line ```data[key] = 'True'  # specify the key, not the value``` how is specifying 'True' not specifying the value there?

Comment: Ok, probably bad wording on my part... What I meant was that in order to change a value in a dictionary, you have to tell the program where to look by referencing the key, otherwise you end up adding another entry into it. Check out this link for a better explanation of how dictionaries work: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't replace the key, rather it creates a new entry with the value from the original key. If you need to simply update it then check if the key is in the dict, change it if it is, then return the new result. Also, you don't need the json lib with requests.

```
import requests

def updatedata(data, key, new_value):
    if key in data:
        data[key] = new_value
    return data

response = requests.get(my_URL, headers=my_headers)
data = response.json()
response = requests.post(myUrl, json=updatedata(data, 'my_key', True))
```

Comment: Okay so this is not working for me and I have a follow up question.  In the function at the end ```return data``` does that not just call response.json() again, which means it is calling the original non-updated requests.get API call?

Comment: No. `data = r.json()` is a python `dict` and you are passing the dict to `updatedata` and returning a dict which is then passed to the `json` arg in the `post` function. `requests` is handling all the dict <-> json conversion for you.